# Cyrillic title in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium

How to get normal output if a title is cyrillic?

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
```

Output is with question marks (can't paste here, doesn't mett quality standards)

Because title is russian. How can I check that a String is correct?

Comment: Works for me with Selenuim 2.53.0 / Firefox 45.0.1. I used yandex.ru, though, because Facebook gives me an English title (probably because of the browser settings). Try printing a random Cyrillic literal string like `"\u0410\u0431\u0412\u0433\u0414"`. If it doesn't work, then the problem is with your terminal or whatever you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly because your output is being sent to a Console that doesn't support the original page's Unicode characters.

Given the following code:

```
@Test public void testCyrillic() {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://yandex.ru");
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
}
```

It produces the following if the encoding is set to ISO-8859-1:

[image]

But [changing your **Run Configuration**](https://decoding.wordpress.com/2010/03/18/eclipse-how-to-change-the-console-output-encoding/) to choose an UTF-8 Console produces:

[image]

I'm assuming Eclipse, but much the same approach works for NetBeans et al.